# Error "Record, object or class type required" when using a wrapper type of an array

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have got two arapper types for easy handling /returning of one-dimensional Arrays, and I want so write a method to convert one to another (a 2d-float-Vector class to a 2d-int-point class). Wrote a simple one, but it just throws some errors I don´t understand.

```
unit UUtil;

interface

uses

    UVector2f, Types, SysUtils;

type

    Vector2fArrayWrapper = array of Vector2f;
    PointArrayWrapper = array of TPoint;

implementation

    function toPointArray(vw : Vector2fArrayWrapper) : PointArrayWrapper;
    var pw : PointArrayWrapper;
        i,x,y : Integer;
    begin
        setLength(pw, vw.length);
        for i := 0 to vw.high do
        begin
            x := round(vw[i].getX());
            y := round(vw[i].getY());
            vw[i] := TPoint(x,y);
        end;
        result := pw;
    end;


end.
```

These are the errors I get:

```
[Error] UUtil.pas(20): Record, object or class type required
[Error] UUtil.pas(21): Record, object or class type required
[Error] UUtil.pas(25): ')' expected but ',' found
[Error] UUtil.pas(27): Declaration expected but identifier 'result' found
[Error] UUtil.pas(28): '.' expected but ';' found
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just a friendly suggestion, when asking a question, remember to be specific in the problem you need help solving. Its not very clear what you need help with. Maybe edit your post to be more specific.

Comment: @bfont How can this question be improved. Code that demonstrates the problem, and a list of compiler errors to explain.

Comment: @David Heffernan This came up in a review for the user's first post. I simply pointed out how he could improve the format of the question by asking a question. Its more of a here is my error but doesn't ask a question specifically, ie. there is nothing close to a question mark in that statement. Just doing what the review asks us to do

Comment: @bfont: The review asks you to offer *constructive* comments. There is nothing wrong with the question asked here; it's specific and clear to developers familiar with Delphi. David is quite correct.

Comment: @KenWhite  I understand you disagree, but I was just offering friendly and constructive advice to edit the question to be more specific about what was being asked. That was my honest effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are not objects, classes or records. They do not have methods defined on them.

Instead of

```
vw.length
```

you must write

```
Length(vw)
```

And likewise for `high`.

Next up, `TPoint` is a type. If you want to make a new one, you use the helper function `Point()`.

Then you assign to `vw[i]`, but surely you mean to assign to `pw[i]`.

Finally, there's no need to introduce a local variable, and then assign `Result` that local variable. You can do all the work directly on `Result`. So, I'd write the code like this:

```
function toPointArray(const vw: Vector2fArrayWrapper): PointArrayWrapper;
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
  setLength( Result, Length(vw));
  for i := 0 to high(vw) do
    Result[i] := Point(round(vw[i].getX), round(vw[i].getY));
end;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. And thanks for pointing out that you can use result directly, I always used it like a "return" statement in other languages

Comment: I'm guessing you are more familiar with C# no?

Comment: This looks more like Java for me. @Michael Hendlich, implicit `Result` is a variable and *syntactic sugar* for `toPointArray := pw`

Comment: @user Interesting. Care to say which aspect is like Java and dislike C#?

Comment: @David Heffernan, honestly I can't say anything specific. Just smelled a faint aroma of *thinking in Java* :)

Comment: @user the equivalent code in Java would be identical to that in C#

Comment: @user Yep, you got lucky... ;-)